# (opencv+python) Getting rid of overlapping lines when using probabilistic hough line transform

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

Good day! I am still very new to python. I am developing a program that would detect pedestrian lines. My problem is that when using Probabilistic Hough transform, lines are detected but they overlap each other. How do I get rid of the overlapped lines? 
Here is my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from calibrate import undist

def auto_canny(img, sigma = 0.5):
    v = np.median(img)

    lower = int(max(0,(1.0-sigma)*v))
    upper = int(min(255,(1.0+sigma)*v))
    edged = cv2.Canny(img, lower, upper)
    edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
    edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)

    return edged

img  = cv2.imread('sample.jpg')
img.shape
green = img[:,:,1]
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(green, (5,5), 0)

autoEdges = auto_canny(blurred)

minLineLength = img.shape[1]-10000
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(image=autoEdges,rho=1,theta=np.pi/500,threshold=10,lines=np.array([]),minLineLength=minLineLength,maxLineGap=90)

a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    xst=lines[i][0][0]
    yst=lines[i][0][1]
    xnd=lines[i][0][2]
    ynd=lines[i][0][3]
    cv2.line(img,(xst, yst), (xnd, ynd), (0,0,255), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)
    l = math.sqrt(((abs(xnd-xst))^2) + ((abs(ynd-yst))^2))
    rho = (xst*ynd - xnd*yst)/l
    dist = abs(rho)
    m = (ynd - yst)/(xnd-xst)   
    print (dist,m)


cv2.imshow('result',img)
cv2.imshow('canny',autoEdges)

k = cv2.waitKey(0)
if k == 27:
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
elif k == ord('a'):
    cv2.imwrite('OUTPUTCANNY.png',autoEdges)
    cv2.imwrite('OUTPUTCANNYWITHHOUGH.png',img)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

These are the output values (rho,slope) for each line:

> (2138.987461393825, 0)
>
> (9352.1609578182488, 0)
>
> (2786.3685089632231, 0)
>
> (459.45861938801005, 0)
>
> (74.176540269582901, 0)
>
> (7768.377424418768, 0)
>
> (4323.5582400556614, 0)
>
> (1457.9223924831122, 0)
>
> (4029.5491996504829, 0)
>
> (353.1785277501566, 0)
>
> (3429.0843443517056, 0)
>
> (687.44444444444446, 0)
>
> (1001.540320481475, 0)
>
> (4891.3687385623834, 0)
>
> (6324.1371540947503, 0)
>
> (5782.5260784389111, 0)
>
> (2142.4394280125407, 0)
>
> (3419.373032213327, 0)
>
> (79.606923443428798, 0)
>
> (4081.4477628728268, 0)
>
> (2548.076237638998, 0)
>
> (2075.2538668232146, 0)
>
> (96.599999999999994, 0)
>
> (28.918275651682048, 0)
>
> (457.23808531952665, 0)
>
> (563.81287237538288, 0)
>
> (4522.6641535572326, 0)
>
> (21.582043818522273, 0)
>
> (2072.2164335243606, 0)
>
> (446.51735688548547, 0)
>
> (4145.9017474324037, 0)
>
> (181.84369168362207, 0)
>
> (2232.0294867294269, 0)
>
> (2003.5982177527055, 0)
>
> (5148.1880307541214, 0)
>
> (654.14939315987181, 0)
>
> (114.49162997063731, 0)
>
> (1256.9505554297596, 0)
>
> (1765.2144695745915, 0)
>
> (835.27600228906385, 0)
>
> (331.66247903554, 0)
>
> (433.90321501459283, 0)
>
> (80.786267723119749, 0)
>
> (678.50865875094041, 0)
>
> (75.599999999999994, 0)
>
> (1698.1082622291476, 0)
>
> (4893.1250194343038, 0)
>
> (870.45171061088456, 0)
>
> (714.65656087382285, 0)
>
> (605.84788121475981, 0)
>
> (2227.8458409210211, 0)
>
> (475.17575695735991, 0)
>
> (6150.4292926708586, 0)
>
> (2489.7061482035415, 0)
>
> (75.894663844041105, 0)
>
> (603.33333333333337, 0)
>
> (973.49884437527714, 0)

Supposedly, there should be 14 lines (edges) to be detected but a total of 72 lines were detected as shown in the data above (rho,slope). Could anyone suggest a way of eliminating these unnecessary lines? Thank you.

Comment: The output is `rho, theta` not `rho, slope`---this is important to note as `theta` is actually perpendicular to the angle of the line. Anyways, can you post some pictures? There are many ways to deal with this problem; for e.g., you could increase `rho` in the `HoughLinesP()` call, you could thin out the lines before detecting lines, or you could merge lines together (e.g. segment and take the median or something). All are viable options for most imagery. If you try one of these and *then* run into problems, you'd more quickly get an answer to the question :). Welcome to Stack!

Comment: Thank you for your response. What are ways of merging lines together?

Answer (score 1):

For that kind of problems, do not think language specific.

Let me clarify your problem first. I will give an example of my previous experiment.
*(I have created a new account, so that my reputation is very low and images are shown as links)*

This was my original image:
[original_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hI6j.jpg)

When I used HoughLinesP, I got a result like this: [houghlinep_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKNkF.png)
I would be happy to see only two lines, but I got a list of similar lines like this:

```
[[[  0  59 104   3]]
 [[  2  59  56  32]]
 [[ 96   3 174  57]]
 [[  4  59  49  36]]
 [[125  25 174  58]]
 [[ 53  34  99   7]]
 [[111  12 165  50]]]
```

My target is to have two lines: [better_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lr1Fz.png)

```
[[  0  59 104   3]
 [ 96   3 174  57]]
```

This is what I wanted because they were on same line with different lengths and very similar angles.

If this solution to my problem is what you need, you can find the angle between two points and check if a similar angle already exists.

A small piece of example:

```
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(img, rho, theta, threshold, np.array([]), min_line_length, max_line_gap)
cleans = np.empty(shape=[0,4], dtype=np.int32)

for l in lines:
        alfa = degrees(atan2(l[0][2]-l[0][0], l[0][3]-l[0][1]))

        if len(cleans) == 0:
            cleans = np.append(cleans, [l[0]], axis=0)
            continue

        similar = False
        for c in cleans:
            beta = degrees(atan2(c[2]-c[0], c[3]-c[1]))
            if abs(alfa-beta) <= 3.5:
                similar = True
                break

        if not similar:
            cleans = np.append(cleans, [l[0]], axis=0)

    print(cleans)

    for line in [cleans]:
        for x1,y1,x2,y2 in line:
            cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),255,2)
```

It finds the angle between two points with **atan2** function.
*Please remember, the code is not optimized.*
It compares the angles with a **threshold**, **3.5** in the example.
If it is lower than the threshold, it thinks that it is a similar line and does not add into the clean array.

In your problem, if you have more than 2 lines and may have similar angles in different coordinates, you have to make an extra check, maybe with a grid size.
If that is the case, please share a couple of screenshots.